# PL/SQL procedure problems

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to write a PL/SQL procedure to count the number of employees in a department by department name. Each department has a department number associated with it that each employee is assigned upon entry. This is my attempt so far. After a lot of practice, I'm still very shaky with PL/SQL. Do I have a blatant logic or syntax error in here anywhere? I'm not asking anyone to do the debugging for me here, but oracle sql's error report doesn't offer much help. Thank you to anyone who answers.

```
create or replace function NumOfEmployee_ByDept
    ( dept_name in department.Dname%type )
    return number
as
    empCount number;

begin
    select count(*) into empCount
    from   department, employee
    where  dno = dnumber
    and    dname = dept_name;

    return(empCount);
end;
```

Comment: I tested it out and your syntax seems ok.  It is possible your client needs a forward slash block terminator at the end.  Can you tell me what client you are using to compile your function?  Can you include the error message in your post?  Thanks

Comment: What is the error you get? What does `show error` give you?

Comment: Does it compile? Does the SQL query work on its own? What problems are you having exactly?

Comment: Thank you for responding everyone. I've been busy the past couple of days, so I'll run it again so I can get an exact error code

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems to be good. Perhaps there is a problem with the grants on the tables. Verify that the schema, in which you're trying to compile this function, got the correct rights for the tables. 
I would recommend you to insert an exception block and to log the delivered error.